# Printing word in one line

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
word = "Marble"
for char in word:
    print char
```

The Output:

> M
>   a
>   r
>   b
>   l
>   e

How can I make console print

> Marble

Answer (score 2):

To print the entire word, the `for` loop is unnecessary.

Instead, use:

```
word = "Marble"
print word 

Marble
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean `print` without a new line.

```
import sys
word = "Marble"
for char in word:
    sys.stdout.write(char)
```

For more detail, [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493386/how-to-print-in-python-without-newline-or-space)