# Strings Iteration - Printing a String Horizontally

Tags: python, python-2.7

So guys, I've been trying to print a string horizontally in the following case, which I iterate through the string and then, I print it. But it doesn't print horizontally. Instead, it prints vertically.
My code:

## Python Version 2.7.10

```
for word in "Monty Python":
    print word
```

The output is:

```
M
o
n
t
y

P
y
t
h
o
n
```

I need your help!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: this looks vertical to me

Comment: What are you talking about? You *are* printing it vertically. Horizontally would look like `Monty Python` which would just be `print "Monty Python"`

Comment: Sorry, bad english, not used to it yet. 
But thanks!

Comment: If you're printing it horizontally, why do you need to iterate through each character? You can just use: print "Monty Python"

Comment: What is the output you are trying to generate? What would you print if the code were working the way you want?

Comment: No, Michael, I just wanted to print Monty Python horizontally, not vertically.
I just did it! Thanks! Just needed to insert a comma in the end of the print statement.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Printing word in one line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31822410/printing-word-in-one-line)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use print_function from __future__.
**CODE 1**

```
from __future__ import print_function
for word in "Monty Python":
    print(word,end=' ')
```

**OUTPUT 1**

```
M o n t y   P y t h o n
```

If you don't want space separated OUTPUT, then replace `end=' '` with `end=''`.

**CODE 2**

```
from __future__ import print_function
for word in "Monty Python":
    print(word,end='')
```

**OUTPUT 2**

```
Monty Python
```

Comment: Perfect! You rock, man! That's exaclty what I was looking for.

Comment: Just did it! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You don't need any iteration. Just do this:

Horizontally:

```
print "Monty Python"
```

Output:

```
Monty Python
```

If you really *must* iterate through it, you should use `sys.stdout.write()` rather than print, because print will put a newline character at the end of every print statement.

```
import sys
for letter in "Monty Python":
    sys.stdout.write(letter)
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll do that!

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the join method to do this.

```
m= "Monty Python"
k = "".join([word for word in m])

print k
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to try using join keyword like:

> > print "".join(word for word in "monty python");

```
output : monty python
```

Comment: Great! Got it, thanks for the help!